# Kubernetes all images are duplicated with same id

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, containers, k3s, containerd

### Problem

While using k3s + external containerd, all the images are duplicated. This includes:

- images automatically pulled by k3s (kube-system, etc.)
- images built locally with cli (using docker/nerdctl compatibility)
- images manually pulled with cli from dockerhub and custom registry

The duplicated image gets untagged every time.

While this problem is not breaking stuff (so far), it's annying as it clutters everything and makes manually deleting images return with an error unless using `--force`.

I'm also concerned about disk space wastage.

I don't recall this ever happening before. Is there anyway this can be resolved? I tried googling around, but didn't find anything about this specific case.

Updating/Reverting version of components doesn't do anything different.

Is this a misconfiguration problem?

Thanks.

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgbdX.png)

### Versions

- crun: 1.8.4
- containerd: 1.6.21
- nerdctl: 1.3.1
- k3s: v1.24.12+k3s1 (no rootless, no apparmor/selinux)
- buildkit: 0.11.6

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-73-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 15 15:18:26 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

### Tried

- Changing components versions
- Googling around on containerd/docker/k3s repos and forums
- Clean setup with new vm and fresh install

### Expected

Building and/or pulling an image does not create 2 with the same id and sizes (one of which is always untagged).

Comment: Not a solution, but you can use `sudo k3s crictl rmi --prune`

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks, I tried the command but it didn't delete the untagged images. Makes me wonder if It's a just a visualization problem due to some strange interaction between components, but in reality the images are not duplicated (?).